# How do i insert element after element in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

So i have this for each function and its basically an item in shop. what i want it to do take the 
container info and make and item in html for each name i guess.

```
<body>
<div id="Collection" style="padding: 20vh 5% 5% 5%;">


 </div>
 </body>
 <script>
    var ItemCollection =

[
    {Name:'ivy',Price:'200$',Picture:''},
    {Name:'eyvo',Price:'300$',Picture:''},
    {Name:'leevo',Price:'400$',Picture:''},




];


   ItemCollection.forEach(generateItem);
$('#Collection').append(content);

      function generateItem(item, index,){
  var body,item,

 body = document.getElementById('Collection').innerHTML ='\n' +
     '        <li class="Shoe"><a href="#'+ item.Name +'\'">\n' +
     '            <div>\n' +
     '                <img class="ItemPicture"\n' +
     '                     

 src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_385,h_385,f_auto,q_auto:
   sensitive,fl_lossy/1783d3e50c9249ab8f75ab280102cb94_9366/
  ivy-park-nite-jogger-shoes.jpg">\n' +
     '\n' +
     '            </div>\n' +
     '            <div class="ItemInfo">\n' +
     '                <p>' + item.Name + '</p>\n' +
     '                <p>'+ item.Price +'</p>\n' +
     '            </div>\n' +
     '            </a>\n' +
     '        </li>\n';

 content = body;

   }
  </script>
```

Current problem is that it just rewrites the item there is currently and the final result is the last item from container. I would like to have there 3 items by the end of the function inside of the div named collection.

Comment: You need an append for each iteration of the loop...or concatenate each iteration to `content` instead of overwriting it each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things i see there,

- Whenever you execute `body = document.getElementById('Collection').innerHTML = ...` you'll be overriding 'Collection' element. Just concatenate the result string to your body variable.
- You forgot to add a '+' at the assignment point of your content variable, either way your just overriding it with new data. Use `content += body` instead.
- Also applying those fixings will let you with 4 items, the original li element and the newly appended ones. Could clean up your 'Collection' element first with `document.getElementById('Collection').innerHTML = ''
  ItemCollection.forEach(generateItem);`

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the innerHtml everytime you function is executed. Replace the '=' with += and it should work like so:

```
document.getElementById('Collection').innerHTML += ...your markup as string
```